# AWS Pinpoint Push Notification for NodeJS has no sound

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-pinpoint

Currently I have this parameter to create a message in pinpoint,

```
{
    ApplicationId: config.PROJECT_ID,
    MessageRequest: {
        Addresses: {
            [token]: {
                ChannelType: 'APNS'
            }
        },
        MessageConfiguration: {
            APNSMessage: {
                Title: notification.title,
                Body: notification.message
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I based my code here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/send-messages-push.html, I checked it using postman and there's no sound when push notification appear, I noticed that there's no parameter available for sound, how can I add a sound in my notification?

In AWS Pinpoint Test Messaging I used this parameter and it's working as expected, but when I tried it and applied it using the above code, it says `"Unexpected key 'aps' found in params.MessageRequest.MessageConfiguration"`

```
{
    APNSMessage: {
        aps: {
            alert: {
                title: notification.title,
                body: notification.message
            },
            sound: 'default'
        }
    }
}
```

I need to add a sound with the value of default using aws-sdk in NodeJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon Pinpoint [SendMessages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/apps-application-id-messages.html#SendMessages) API doesn't expect/allow the "aps" dictionary to be specified when sending the push notification using a standard message.

- To send push notification with sound using standard message, kindly refer to the following working sample code snippet :

  ```
  // Specify the parameters to pass to the API.
  var params = {
    ApplicationId: '4fd13a40xxxxxxxx',
    MessageRequest: {
      Addresses: {
        ["token from APNS"]: {
          ChannelType: 'APNS'
        }
      },
      MessageConfiguration: {
          APNSMessage: {
          Title: 'TEST',
          Body: 'This is a sample push notification sent from Amazon Pinpoint by using Nodejs SDK',
          Sound: 'default',
        }
      }
    }
  };
  ```
- To send push notification with sound using the "aps" dictionary, then you'll need to use :

**( i ) RawContent** property:  If using Pinpoint SDK/REST API/CLI.The RawContent property needs to be defined/specified as a JSON-formatted string as illustrated below :

```
// Specify the parameters to pass to the API.
var params = {
  ApplicationId: '4fd13a40xxxxxxxx',
  MessageRequest: {
    Addresses: {
      "token from APNS": {
        ChannelType: 'APNS'
      }
    },
    MessageConfiguration: {
        APNSMessage: {
        RawContent : '{"aps":{"alert":"Hello, this is a test push notification!","sound":"default"}}' // If you define 'RawContent' here, everything ("message") else in the "MessageConfiguration" will be ignored.

      }
    }
  }
};
```

**( ii ) RawMessage** property : If using Pinpoint console as illustrated below :

```
{
    APNSMessage: {
        aps: {
            alert: {
                title: notification.title,
                body: notification.message
            },
            sound: 'default'
        }
    }
}
```

*this explains why, when you tested in AWS Pinpoint console and selected Test Messaging & Raw Message then the notification worked correctly with sound.*

Comment: I already done this implementation, btw thanks for the answer. It looks like the same to what I did :)